# NYSE Early Close Rules (July 4th and Dec. 25th)

Tags: exchange, nyse

Does the NYSE provide a list of rules for determining when to close at 1:00 for a holiday?  I have found a list of upcoming half-days [here](http://www.nyx.com/en/holidays-and-hours/nyse) but I would like to know the rules so that I don't have to hard-code them in my application.

I found a list of all of the dates on which the NYSE closed early in its history [here](http://www.nyse.com/pdfs/closings.pdf)*.  I could discern three rules for half-days that I would like to verify:

- Thanksgiving: the Friday after Thanksgiving is always a half day (close at 1:00).
- Christmas: if Dec 24th is a Mon, Tues, Wed, or Thur, close at 1:00.
- July 4th: if July 4th is a Tues, Wed, or Fri, close at 1:00 on the previous day.  If July 4th is a Thur, close at 1:00 on the next day.

The list of upcoming holidays shows that Wednesday, July 3, 2013 is a half-day.  This conflicts with what looks like their previous policies.  I'm guessing that in the future, July 5th will never be a half-day and that July 3rd will be a half-day if it falls on a Mon, Tues, Wed, or Thur (similar to the Dec 24th rule).

*According to that historic list I linked, the NYSE used to be open on Saturdays.  I thought that was interesting.

Comment: Rather than hard-coding it into your application, you could have it read from a config file since they publish the schedule ahead of time. Also, if you think you're going to code it and not update it *at least* once a year you're wrong.

Comment: I shouldn't have said "hard-code".  I would probably store those dates in a database somewhere.

Comment: Any idea on post market hours on these half days? I use this data https://raw.githubusercontent.com/QuantConnect/Lean/master/Data/market-hours/market-hours-database.json but not sure how to deal with early closes and post market (if any)

Answer (score 2):

I emailed one of my contacts at NYSE, who replied that there is no rule or policy governing half days (other than that the exchange must be opened for a full day on the last day of the year).